# Neo4J 3.3.3 database got corrupted as there was not enough disk space and no way to fix it?

Tags: neo4j, corruption

I ran out of disk space and my Neo4J 3.3.3 database doesn't start anymore showing the following error:

> 2018-04-16 21:10:35.148+0000 ERROR Failed to start Neo4j: Starting
>   Neo4j failed: Component
>   'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@7e5c856f' was
>   successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see the attached
>   cause exception "null. At position LogPosition{logVersion=250,
>   byteOffset=198709181} and entry version V3_0_10". Starting Neo4j
>   failed: Component
>   'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@7e5c856f' was
>   successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see the attached
>   cause exception "null. At position LogPosition{logVersion=250,
>   byteOffset=198709181} and entry version V3_0_10".

When I run `neo4j-admin check-consistency --database=graph.db` I get:

> unexpected error: null. At position LogPosition{logVersion=250,
>   byteOffset=198709181} and entry version V3_0_10

So probably some logs got corrupted.

Does Neo4J have any tools to fix this situation?

I looked at https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-javascript-driver/issues/300 - but it didn't help me as I don't even get any error message just the one above.

I tried https://github.com/jexp/store-utils but when I run

`copy-store.sh community ~/neo4j-community-3.3.3/data/databases/graph.db ~/target.db`

it says

> [ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :  [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------- [ERROR] /home/noduslabs/repair/store-utils/src/main/java/org/neo4j/tool/StoreCopy.java:[96,18]
>   error: cannot find symbol [ERROR]  class StoreCopy
>   /home/noduslabs/repair/store-utils/src/main/java/org/neo4j/tool/StoreCopy.java:[96,59]
>   error: cannot find symbol [ERROR]  class StoreCopy
>   /home/noduslabs/repair/store-utils/src/main/java/org/neo4j/tool/StoreCopy.java:[97,37]
>   error: cannot find symbol

Running that same store-utils but branch 32 seem to go further but then the same error occurs:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.1:java (default-cli) on project
>   store-util: An exception occured while executing the Java class. null:
>   InvocationTargetException: Error starting
>   org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory,
>   /home/noduslabs/neo4j-community-3.3.3/data/databases/graph.db:
>   Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.recovery.Recovery@4168eb66' failed to
>   initialize. Please see the attached cause exception "null. At position
>   LogPosition{logVersion=250, byteOffset=198709181} and entry version
>   V3_0_10". -> [Help 1]
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to
>   execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.1:java
>   (default-cli) on project store-util: An exception occured while
>   executing the Java class. null
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:213)

So basically I'm stuck and there's not way to fix the DB, right?

Comment: after trying different things, I copied the graph.db and opened it with the latest 3.4.0 beta02 enterprise version I have installed on my local Mac machine. it worked. I read somewhere 3.4 automatically fixes such errors. can I now simply copy that graph.db back to the 3.3.3 version on my Linux server or some data would be corrupted because of new datastores, etc?

Comment: If this solved your issue, could you post it as an answer and accept it so others can easily find it?

Comment: @RebeccaNelson well that didn't really solve my issue, as my issue is that there are no tools in Neo4J to fix a database corrupted because of disk space... So I'd rather wait for somebody from Neo4J to comment on this issue. Having to copy a DB manually into a beta 3.4 version of a database to fix it is not a really good solution...